# Clamp variable within range

Tags: r, clamp

Given two values `x` and `b`, I want a function to clamp `x` to fall within `[-b, b]`. In particular:

- If `x` is less than or equal to `-b`, then the function returns `-b`;
- If `x` is greater than `-b` and less than `b`, then the function returns `x`;
- If `x` is greater than or equal to `b`, then the function returns `b`.

In R I wrote the following function `truncfn`. Only part of this function works. Where did I make mistake? Is there an easier way to do this?

```
b <- 5

truncfn <- function(x){
  if((x<(-b))||(x==-b)) -b 
  if((x>(-b))&&(x<b)) x 
  if((x>b)||(x==b)) b
}

truncfn(10)
5
truncfn(4)
truncfn(-10)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use the `pmin` and `pmax` functions to do this is a single expression without `if` statements:

```
b <- 5
x <- seq(-10, 10)
pmax(pmin(x, b), -b)
# [1] -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

You could have fixed your function by replacing the second and third `if` statements with `else if` statements (or alternately using `return(b)`, `return(x)` and `return(-b)`). Here is a working version (I've taken the liberty to use `<=` instead of separately checking with `<` and `==`):

```
truncfn <- function(x){
  if (x <= -b) -b
  else if (x > -b && x < b) x 
  else b
}
truncfn(10)
# [1] 5
truncfn(4)
# [1] 4
truncfn(-10)
# [1] -5
```

However note that the function I wrote with `pmin` and `pmax` can take a whole vector as input, while yours is limited to taking a single number.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `raster::clamp`

```
library(raster)
b <- 5
v <- -10:10
raster::clamp(v, -b, b)
# [1] -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  5  5  5  5  5
```